# Overriding Contact Controller - No difference

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers, contact-us

After running through every tutorial on the internet about overriding core controllers I resort to posting here.

```
Magento: 1.9.1.1 community

Namespace: Tft

Module Name: Customcontact
```

Files:

**/app/code/local/Tft/Customcontact/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tft_Customcontact>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Tft_Customcontact>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customcontact>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Tft_Customcontact before="Mage_Contacts">Tft_Customcontact</Tft_Customcontact>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customcontact>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

/app/etc/modules/Tft_Customcontact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tft_Customcontact>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Tft_Customcontact>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And the controller:
**/app/code/local/Tft/Customcontact/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
class Tft_Customcontact_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                /**************************************************************/
                $fileName = '';
                if (isset($_FILES['customerimg']['name']) && $_FILES['customerimg']['name'] != '') {
                    try {
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['customerimg']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('customerimg');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')); //add more file types you want to allow
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts';
                        if(!is_dir($path)){
                            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                        }
                        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
                /**************************************************************/

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */

                /**************************************************************/
                //sending file as attachment
                $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'contacts' . DS . $fileName;
                if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                    $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);
                    $attachment   = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                    $attachment->filename = $fileName;
                }
                /**************************************************************/

                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('If you see this at all your custom controller works.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```

All cache has been flushed dozens of times. The module is very clearly enabled in the admin panel. Yet it only shows the success message from the default system controller. When submitting the contact form I should be getting: "If you see this at all your custom controller works."

If I override the core file directly it works, of course, but obviously overriding core is not ideal.

Anyone see anything out of ordinary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There issue in

```
Tft_Customcontact.xml



 <codepool>local</codepool>
```

should be

```
 <codePool>local</codePool>
```

P should Capital word

See how to overrider controller check at [here](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/)

Comment: Well there it is. I knew magento was picky about casing but I overlooked that difference between magento's example and inchoo's. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a difference to CE 1.9 but in CE 1.8 the config.xml routers-part must be like this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Tft_Customcontact before="Mage_Contacts">Tft_Customcontact</Tft_Customcontact>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Means: "contacts" instead of "customcontact"