# Overriding controller

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I have followed few instructions found in this forum, but I must be missing something. I am trying to override Contacts controller, specifically postAction method. Here is what I have got:

```
Magento version: 1.9.3.1;
Namespace: MageOverload;
Module: ContactsModule;
```

**/app/code/local/MageOverload/ContactsModule/etc/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageOverload_ContactsModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MageOverload_ContactsModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contactsmodule>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MageOverload_ContactsModule before="Mage_Contacts">MageOverload_ContactsModule</MageOverload_ContactsModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contactsmodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**/app/etc/modules/MageOverload_ContactsModule.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageOverload_ContactsModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MageOverload_ContactsModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/MageOverload/ContactsModule/controllers/IndexController.php**:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
class MageOverload_ContactsModule_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction() {
        //... custom code
    }
}
```

I have flushed cache, custom module is visible via magento admin panel, but still the system is using Mage core files for Contacts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70965/overriding-contact-controller-no-difference - I have followed these instructions, but still the problem occurs.

Comment: Try changing your package name to **Mageoverload** and module name to **Contactsmodule** and update folder names and class names as per.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller rewrite XML part should look like this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MageOverload_ContactsModule before="Mage_Contacts">MageOverload_ContactsModule</MageOverload_ContactsModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

As you can see instead of using `<contactsmodule>` node we are here using `<contacts>` node. `<contacts>` is the router node which is using by `Mage_Contacts` module.

After this change is done, do not forget to flush the cache again.

#### Free Tip:

It is a good practice to keep dependency in your module as shown below.

File : `MageOverload_ContactsModule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageOverload_ContactsModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Contacts />
            </depends>
        </MageOverload_ContactsModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This clearly indicates that, your module has a dependency on `Mage_Contacts` module and thus Magento will load your module only after `Mage_Contacts` is loaded.

Comment: Thank You very much. Your answer is more than I expected. All the best for You!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

app\etc\modules\MageOverload_ContactsModule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageOverload_ContactsModule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageOverload_ContactsModule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app\code\local\MageOverload\ContactsModule\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageOverload_ContactsModule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageOverload_ContactsModule>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <contactsmodule>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>MageOverload_ContactsModule</module>
            <frontName>contactsmodule</frontName>
          </args>
      </contactsmodule>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
        <rewrite>        
            <mageoverload_contactsmodule_contacts_indexcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/contacts/index/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_Contacts_IndexController  -->
                <to>/contactsmodule/contacts_index/</to> <!-- MageOverload_ContactsModule_Contacts_IndexController  -->
            </mageoverload_contactsmodule_contacts_indexcontroller>
        </rewrite>

  </global>  
</config>
```

app\code\local\MageOverload\ContactsModule\controllers\Contacts\IndexController.php

```
require_once "Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php";  
class MageOverload_ContactsModule_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController{

    public function postAction()
    {
       //custom code
    }


}
```

Hope it will help you.