# How to override app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I want to override core class of Magento 1: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php`
How I can do that?

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182857/overriding-controller?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182857/overriding-controller)